# Axios call is failing in NestJs

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, nestjs

My axios request failed with status code 401 in Nestjs while it works fine with postman. What is wrong with the code?
Here is my code:

```
async createKeycloakUser(data: any):Promise<any>
  {   
    const token = await this.newKeyToken(data); 
    var string = JSON.stringify(token);
    var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
    var bearerToken = objectValue['access_token'];

    return this.httpService.axiosRef.post(
      `localhost:8080/admin/realms/new/users`,
      querystring.stringify({
        firstName:"Test",
        lastName:"last Test",
        email:"abc@tests.com",
        enabled:"true",
        username:"new-user",
      })
      ,
      {
        headers: { 
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          
        }
      }
      ).then(function(response) {                
        return response.data;   
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)     
    });     
  }
```

Here is the controller code:

```
  @Public()
  @Post('/keyusers')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Set User' })
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  async createKeycloakUser(
    @Body()
    payload: keycloakuserDTO,
  ) {
    return await this.userService.createKeycloakUser(payload);
  }
```

Comment: It probably needs a scheme on the url, like https.

Comment: @danh i tried with this as well like https:// http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/new/users. 
i missed to paste that path here. This is not the issue. Its giving error 401

Comment: A 401 is usually an `Unauthorized` call. Why? Couldn't say unless you're given more details that you haven't shared with us. As you're also running the server you're calling to locally, check that server's logs for extra info too